# R ReporteRs - Flextable for ppt - how to change column widths and keep the whole size

Tags: r, reporters

I like the ReporteRs package, cannot, however, find out how to format the Flextable and keep its size.
If I want one column to be 3x wider than the others I can set it but the table does not keep the space prepared in PPT.

This is part of the original code from the ReporteRs home website. It should work for anyone with installed ReporteRs package and the output path.

```
library( ReporteRs )

mydoc <- pptx( )

mydoc <- addSlide( mydoc, "Two Content" )
mydoc <- addTitle( mydoc, "First 10 lines of iris" )

MyFTable <- FlexTable(iris[1:10,] )
mydoc <- addFlexTable( mydoc, MyFTable )

mydoc <- addParagraph( mydoc, value = c("", "Hello World!") )

writeDoc(mydoc, "C:/DATAOLD/REPORTERS/REP.pptx" )
```

It works well and the output slide looks like this:

[image: Output1]

After changing the column widths the table does not fit the space prepared for it anymore

```
library( ReporteRs )

mydoc <- pptx( )

mydoc <- addSlide( mydoc, "Two Content" )
mydoc <- addTitle( mydoc, "First 10 lines of iris" )

twidth<-c(1,1,1,1,3)
MyFTable <- FlexTable(iris[1:10,] )
MyFTable <- setFlexTableWidths( MyFTable, widths = twidth)
mydoc <- addFlexTable( mydoc, MyFTable )

mydoc <- addParagraph( mydoc, value = c("", "Hello World!") )

writeDoc(mydoc, "C:/DATAOLD/REPORTERS/REP.pptx" )
```

[image: Output2]

I can understand that the table is simply wider now.. even though I believed that its size is always changed to fit the size of the placeholder unless special size parameters are present.

Is there any simple solution to this problem? I simply need some columns to be wider than others and keep the whole table within the placeholder.
Rescaling the twidth

```
twidth<-twidth*length(twidth)/sum(twidth)
```

is not a solution since some columns are then too narrow.

[image: Output3]

Thanks for any comments.

EDIT:  According to David Gohel's comment on Github
https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs/issues/146#issuecomment-258485791

it is not easily possible to control the height of the Flextable at the moment.

The width is partly controllable through the font and column widths.